# How to store dynamic generated views in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Consider scenario there are multiple users in my system and I have access level, roles and permission.

Now Admin decides every sub user what they will see in their dashboard.

Admin will drag and drop widgets that may be predefined or may be dynamic.

So now my question is how to store that generated view HTML in Database or in a storage directory as a separate view file(blade.php) for individual User?

I'm confused what to use and which is better for performance and rendering the content.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have an id on each widget then as admin you move the widgets around, then you could store the order of the widgets in the database, then when users loads the page it can grab the order from the database and display.

Comment: force of habit!